# Podio js: Revoke access and refresh tokens

Tags: oauth-2.0, podio

Is it possible to revoke:

1. Access tokens;
2. Refresh tokens;

using the Podio-js library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invalidate the current user `access_token` using the [Invalidate Tokens](https://developers.podio.com/doc/oauth-authorization/invalidate-tokens-7997943) endpoint.
The access token can still be refreshed using the `refresh_token`

```
var PodioJS = require('podio-js');
PodioJS.request('POST', '/oauth/token/invalidate', {});
```

Using the [Invalidate Grant](https://developers.podio.com/doc/oauth-authorization/invalidate-grant-7997965) endpoint instead invalidate **both** tokens, which means that the user is effectively logged out.

```
var PodioJS = require('podio-js');
PodioJS.request('POST', '/oauth/grant/invalidate', {});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you can find a solution [here](http://podio.github.io/podio-js/authentication/).

Comment: No answer there unfortunately.